# How to prevent PowerShell from changing environment variables?

Tags: c#, powershell

Following test fails, because the `PowerShell` object changes the path of the caller process:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management.Automation;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;


namespace Helpers.Tests.ShellHelper {
    [TestClass]
    public class PowerShellEnvAlteration_Tests {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestPath() {
            var searchTarget = @"C:\LandingZone";

            using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create()) {
                powerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("env:Path",
                    $"{searchTarget}{Path.PathSeparator}{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH")}");
            }

            var pathDirs = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH").Split(Path.PathSeparator);
            Assert.IsFalse(pathDirs.Contains(searchTarget));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I prevent it? is it possible to completely isolate this `PowerShell` object/execution?

Comment: Did you try to use out of process `Runspace` instead of default in-process one?

Comment: @PetSerAl, yes, but then I get `System.Management.Automation.PSNotSupportedException` when calling `powerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.PSVariable.Set(...)`

Comment: @Tar You can not access `SessionStateProxy.PSVariable` of remote `Runspace`. https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master@%7B2019-01-14%7D/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/remoting/client/remoterunspace.cs#L2964

Answer (score 2):

[PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

Because **environment variables are intrinsically [whole-]*process*-scoped**, you **need an *out-of-process* runspace** to get the desired behavior.

By contrast, `PowerShell.Create()` by itself, without explicit assignment of a runspace via the resulting instance's `.Runspace` property, defaults to an *in-process* runspace, and modifying an environment variable through that runspace then invariably affects the caller running in the same process as well.

To modify your code to use an out-of-process runspace, do the following:

```
// ...
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

// ...

// Create an out-of-process runspace...
using (var runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(null))
{
  runspace.Open(); // ... open it ...
  using (PowerShell powerShell = PowerShell.Create())
  {
    powerShell.Runspace = runspace; // ... and assign it to the PowerShell instance.

    // Now setting $env:PATH only takes effect for the separate process
    // in which the runspace is hosted.
    // Note: `powerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("env:Path", ...)` does 
    // does NOT work with OUT-OF-PROCESS runspaces, so a call to
    // `Set-Item env:PATH ...` is used to modify the other process' PATH env. var.
    // (Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable() is NOT an option, because
    //  it would modify the *calling* process' environment).
    powerShell.AddCommand("Set-Item")
      .AddParameter("LiteralPath", "env:Path")
      .AddParameter("Value", $"{searchTarget}{Path.PathSeparator}{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path")}")
      .Invoke();
    powerShell.Commands.Clear();

    // ...

  }

}
```

Note: The above uses a call to `Set-Item env:Path ...` in order to modify `$env:PATH` in the out-of-process runspace, because, as PetSerAl points out, unlike in *in-process* runspaces, using `powerShell.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("env:Path", ...)` creates a *PowerShell* variable literally named `env:Path` rather than modifying *environment* variable `PATH`, as of Windows PowerShell v5.1 / PowerShell Core 6.2.0-preview.3; see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8643)